# HTTP authentication without pop-up?

Tags: php, authentication, basic-authentication

Can I use [HTTP authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) without the pop-up window?

Comment: I think by setting headers based over the AUTH map like BASIC or DIGEST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Thats just the point of the http authentification: you don't need to implement any interaction whatsoever. So if you need another implementaion, you have to do it yourself.

This seems to be a good tutorial on writing your own authentification using cookies:
http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Writing-a-Basic-Authentication-System-in-PHP/